# Create a Unique Check Constraint with CONCAT in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, matrix

**Problem:** Create a master table that holds distance between two points (say `a` and `b`), however I don't want to create two records `[('a', 'b', 10), ('b', 'a', 10)]` for this I thought of creating a SQL table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mwDistance (
    _id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    LOC_A VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    LOC_B VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    DIST  NUMERIC(5, 2) NOT NULL,

    CreatedOn DATE NOT NULL,
    isActive  INTEGER CHECK(isActive IN (0, 1)),

    CONSTRAINT uq_lane_name_ab UNIQUE (LOC_A, LOC_B, isActive),
    CONSTRAINT uq_lane_name_ba UNIQUE (LOC_B, LOC_A, isActive),
    CONSTRAINT uq_global_lane_name UNIQUE (
        LOC_A || '-' || LOC_B || '-' || isActive,
        LOC_B || '-' || LOC_A || '-' || isActive
    )
);
```

This gives an error: `"Result: expressions prohibited in PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints"`

**Usage:** Since I only have around 10k records, I will parse the data in python using a dictionary like:

```py
mwDistance = {
  'a' : {'a' : 5,'b' : 10, ...},
  ...,
  'b' : {'a' : 10, 'b' : 4, ...},
  ...
}

# thus, to retrieve I can simply:
print(mwDistance['a']['b'])
>> 10
print(mwDistance['b']['a'])
>> 10
```

Not sure if this is the best approach. However, would like some help on:

1. *either* fixing the create statement to not allow duplicate entry w/o any external functionalities,
2. *or* an alternate solution to store the same information and easy retrieval using python.

EDIT: Tried to create an `UNIQUE INDEX` however failed with error `"Result: subqueries prohibited in CHECK constraints"`:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_global_lane_name 
ON mwDistance (
    CASE WHEN LOC_A < LOC_B THEN LOC_A ELSE LOC_B END,
    CASE WHEN LOC_A < LOC_B THEN LOC_B ELSE LOC_A END,
    isActive
);
```